# How to include php query within website framework

Tags: php, function, frameworks, structure

I am having trouble with my PHP framework. I am currently not using a framework template, I have chosen not to use one because I'm not exactly sure how to use one.   This is how my code is structured:

Index.php:

```
<?php   
require_once( 'page_elements.php' );
?>
<body>

<?php echo content();?>

</body>
```

page_elements.php:

```
<?php
function content() {
?>
 <form id='signup' method='post' action=''>
    <input type="text" size="17" name="signup" title="Email" style="color:#888;" value="Enter email address" />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'> </input>
 </form>
<?php if(isset($formComplete)) {
         echo "<p> $formComplete </p>";  
     }


} ?>
```

form php script:

```
if(isset($_POST('Email'))
{
 if($_POST('Email') !== ''){
  mysql code enters email address...
 $formComplete = 'Thanks, your email address has been taken';
 }
}
```

The $formComplete comes from the php script that deals with the data from the form. My question is how do I include the script to deal with the data from the submitted form on my website where the function content() will still recognise the $formComplete?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

whether the form is complete or not will be checked in the script where `$formComplete` lives and not in the script where the form is being submitted. `formComplete` does something with the date sent from form, right?

then check the form validness with js in front-end and leave your `formComplete` in that script, where it does further server-side actions.. 
pseudo-action:

fron-end:

```
form submit
check form with js
send form data to backend
```

backend:

```
formComplete 
do something with data
say your thanks
```

Comment: thanks. My question i suppose is how to i say thanks in the <p> tag?! cheers

Comment: easy.. ``echo "thanks";`` you will catch this echo back in your index.php if you were using ajax..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just send the $formComplete as a parameter to your function:

```
function content($formComplete = '') {
...
}

echo content($formComplete);
```

Also, even though it's probably not a good practice, since the $formComplete is basically a function that deals with the form data (whether $_POST or $_GET), you can actually call the function that handles the $formComplete variable inside your content() function. For example:

```
function content(){
$formComplete = get_form_complete($_POST); // or $_GET depending on your form method type

// do the rest here
}
```